# MYSQL log_bin_trust_function_creators

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create triggers on a mysql database. In doing this I encountered the following error:

`You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)`

After a bit of research on [the MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html) I pretty much understood that when creating triggers or store procedures you run into the risk of them being non deterministic and mess up the binary log. This is because the binary log won't be able to be used correctly for replication or data recovery if any of these functions might produce a different result given the same inputs.

The quick fix for this is to tell mysql not to worry by giving the user SUPER privileges or by setting `log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1` (as reported by [different articles](http://www.logikdev.com/tag/log_bin_trust_function_creators/) and [stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601692/mysql-amazon-rds-error-you-do-not-have-super-priviledges))

I can do that, but I use triggers as a logging mechanism and I call `NOW()` inside it. This is clearly non deterministic.

Reading a bit further though they seem to say that these issues are only present if `binlog_format` is set to `STATEMENT` or in other words if the db logs mysql statements that have been run, and not the resulting rows.

So recapping, if my binlog_format is set to `MIXED` or `ROW` i should not be worring about any of this and just set `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to be able to create these triggers, otherwise since my triggers are non deterministic I could run into possible recovery and replication issues.

Is my understanding of this correct? Sorry for the lengthy explanation but I want to make sure my interpretation of the docs is accurate

Answer (score 0):

Non-deterministic functions like `NOW()` are handled in statement replication by having a fake time record and other workarounds so that a replication stream will end up with a consistent slave as expected.

`log_bin_trust_function_creators` is about the procedures/function really being deterministic when they are marked as such. It can be set globally rather than giving SUPER permissions.

Replication format has tradeoffs however if you aren't doing bulk deletes probably a MIXED/ROW format will enable you do avoid a lot of the complications around triggers/procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I wish that the documentation was a bit more clear about this. But I think both `STATEMENT` and `MIXED` are dangerous modes here and you want to use `ROW`.

[According to the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html):

> When using row-based logging, no distinction is made in the treatment of safe and unsafe statements.

Which implies that `log_bin_trust_function_creators` shouldn't matter when `binlog_format` is `ROW`.

However, even when using row-based replication non-deterministic function declarations still produce the `ERROR 1418` `This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)` error without `log_bin_trust_function_creators` enabled.

Maybe it still issues this warning because even in row-based mode there are still some types of non-deterministic functions that are unsafe for replication (for example, a [DEFAULT clause that refers to a nondeterministic function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html)). So this warning still applies to say "make sure you know what you are doing".

Anyway, it seems to me that if you need to use non-deterministic functions your best bet is to use `binlog_format=ROW` with `log_bin_trust_function_creators` and make sure that your functions and procedures don't have any dangerous edge cases like that.